# Django Project App Urls Page Not Found (404)

Tags: django

I still new to Django and I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAn1KpPlN2w) tutorial in YouTube. I can't proceed to the next tutorial because I hit an error.

When I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/music. I get this error.
[image]

Check my code below:

mysite urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

music urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

music views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you try this [http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/)

Comment: @RajaSimon Still the same error. Page not found at /music/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have not saved the `project/urls.py` file.

Or to check whether the `music` is set in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: Didn't notice that. I was using XCode and everything was not saved at all. Even if I used save a couple of times. Thanks.